# Python dataframe using .apply to replace for loop

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, apply

For python code:

```
def filtering(price):
    global cash , stock,buyPrice,sellPrice, buy_data,sell_data,trade_price,test2
    if price.iloc[0] >price.iloc[1] and cash == True:
        buyPrice.append(price, ignore_index=True)
        cash = False
        stock = True
```

I'm trying to append a dataframe into another data frame.
Then I apply this function into:

```
toworkdata.apply(filtering)
```

The thing is, buyPrice gives me nothing in return. why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

You have assign new value to the data frame like below

```
def filtering(price):
    global cash , stock,buyPrice,sellPrice, buy_data,sell_data,trade_price,test2
    if price.iloc[0] >price.iloc[1] and cash == True:
        # Edit here
        buyPrice = buyPrice.append(price, ignore_index=True)
        cash = False
        stock = True
```

Comment: i got the answer in 1 rows × 2459 columns while i want it to be 2459 rows x 1  columns. why is that so? thank you